# jQuery submit is not catching submit event after ajax loading of content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I load content to my popup with jQuery Ajax load function and I use submit function in load functions callback function, but for some reason event is not fired at all. (I use jQuery jquery-1.3.2.min.js)

```
$('.popup-container').load(url, function(){ 
    /** Do some stuff here */
    $("form").submit(function() { 
        alert("Form submitted!");       
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

As of jQuery 1.7, the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method [is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.7/). It will be removed in jQuery 1.9. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) in preference to `.live()`.

---

#### Original Answer

You can fix this by using the jQuery method `live()`. Using `live()` with `submit()` has been added to jQuery 1.4 so you should get an update. [Here is a video tutorial on using `live()` with `submit()`](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1772-jQuery-1-4-Live-Form-Submit-Support.htm).

When using the live function your code should look like this:

```js
$("form").live('submit' , function() { 
    alert("Form submitted!");       
    return false;
});

$('.popup-container').load(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.  using `$(document).on('submit', '#form', function() {`

instead of:
`$("#form").submit(function() {`

solved the problem.  hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe return false stops it from submitting.

Comment: Hi, yes it should but for some reason form gets submitted by this code.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim said, jQuery 1.4 has added support for submit handlers in the `live` function. His code should work for you.

If you can't use jQuery 1.4 for whatever reason, you'll need to reapply your handlers:

```
function applyHandlers(query) {
    $(query).submit(function() { alert('foo'); return false; });
}

applyHandlers('form');

$('.popup-container').load(url, function() {
    applyHandlers($('form', this));
});
```

There's much more elegant ways to do this, but you get the basic idea.